# DELTA SEQUENCES

Tags: functional-analysis, generating-functions

If $f(x)$ is nonnegative function satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx =1$ show that ${mf(mx)}$ is delta sequence.

We need to check $ lim  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {mf(mx)} f(x)dx  $ = $f(0)$ as $m$ goes to  $\infty $. But I can not. 
Please, help me ?

Comment: Surely a few copies of $f$ should be a $g$ drawn from your test functions? Have you tried a change of variables combined with a dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: First of all, you should use different functions in the integral, one is $f$, the other a test function $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} m \, f(mx) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \{ x' = mx \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x') \, \phi(x'/m) \, dx' \\
\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x') \, \phi(0) \, dx' 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x') \, dx' \, \phi(0)
= \phi(0),
$$
where the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) has been used when taking the limit.